# Run with TestNG option is not coming on my Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have installed the dependency of TestNG through maven.
But still run with test NG option was not coming so i install TestNG in my eclipse from INSTALL software but still run with test NG option not coming
[image]

I tried putting external jar files as well
tried changing test to compile in POM file for testNG but still no results
TestNG plugin also installed

Comment: Restart the Eclipse or reinstall the application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow only one single approach among the following but not all:

- Downloading and putting external jar files.
- Install TestNG in my eclipse from Install New Software
- Dependency of [testng](/questions/tagged/testng) through [maven](/questions/tagged/maven)

---

Assuming you only have the [testng maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng), you need to perform the following steps:

- *`mvn clean`*: This command cleans the Maven project by deleting the target directory.
- *`mvn install`*: This command builds the Maven project and installs the project files (JAR, WAR, pom.xml, etc.) to the local repository.
- *`mvn test`*: This command runs the test cases of the project.

---

If you still don't find the testng related jars added to your project then perform `Maven` > `Update Project...`

[image: UpdateProject]

---

### References

Some useful links:

- [Maven Commands Cheat Sheet](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/maven-commands-options-cheat-sheet)